# C Registry Functions In Windows API

Tags: c, winapi, readability

RegOpenKeyEx()

I want to printf("Success") or printf("Failure") depending on if the function fails or succeeds

How would I do such a conditional while keeping it neat and legible?

I am wanting to stay away from this :

```
if (RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,"HUGE LONG KYEY STRUCTURE HERE",0,KEY_SET_VALUE) != 0 )
{
   //CODE 
}
```

Comment: I think he just wants to make it readable.

Answer (score 3):

Are you asking how to check why it failed?

"A nonzero error code defined in Winerror.h indicates failure. To get a generic description of the error, call FormatMessage with the FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM flag set."

So.. ERROR_SUCCESS if succeeded, error code if it fails.

Answer (score 1):

After checking the unedited question, I think the only thing you can do is to break up the    statement into multiple statements like this:

```
const char* regKey = "BIG_STRING......";
DWORD errorCode = RegOpenKeyEx(...);
if(ERROR_SUCCESS == errorCode)
{ 
  //Rest of the code
}
else
{
  //Error handling
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use newlines, or name things or both,

```
 LONG result = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
                            "HUGE LONG KYEY STRUCTURE HERE",
                             0,KEY_SET_VALUE);
 if(result != 0 ) {
    ...
```

or perhaps

```
 LPCTSTR keypath = "HUGE LONG KYEY STRUCTURE HERE";
 if( RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,keypath,0,KEY_SET_VALUE) != 0 ) {
     ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not return ERROR_SUCCESS when it does not succeed.  Is that what you mean?

for multiple checks of error codes use:

```
LONG errors = 0;

errors += abs( RegKeyOpenEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,"HUGE LONG KYEY STRUCTURE HERE",0,KEY_SET_VALUE) );
errors += abs( RegKeyOpenEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,"HUGE LONG KYEY STRUCTURE HERE",0,KEY_SET_VALUE) );
errors += abs( RegKeyOpenEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,"HUGE LONG KYEY STRUCTURE HERE",0,KEY_SET_VALUE) );
errors += abs( RegKeyOpenEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,"HUGE LONG KYEY STRUCTURE HERE",0,KEY_SET_VALUE) );
errors += abs( RegKeyOpenEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,"HUGE LONG KYEY STRUCTURE HERE",0,KEY_SET_VALUE) );

if( errors > 0 )
{
  print( "OMG It went wrong!\n" );
}
else
{
  print( "Hero!\n" );
}
```

Comment: This returns error codes, not Boolean values, so you should watch out for integer overflows and positive/negative return values. Even Win32 API functions that return BOOL can return 1 or -1 in different situations (e.g. GetMessage).

Comment: @bk1e - but a look at winerror.h shows there are no negative error codes and overflow should be quite unlikely unless you are calling it more than a million times or so.  Your concerns are unfounded and uneducated.

Answer (score 0):

You could instead use the ternary operator:

```
bool success = (RegKeyOpenEx(...) == ERROR_SUCCESS);
printf("%s\n", success ? "Success" : "Failure");
```